# How do I stop script/runner email filter from logging STDIN?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, stdin

I have a method in a model which processes an incoming bounced email. In cPanel, I have an email account forwarder called `eblast-bounce@mydomain.com` which is set to pipe to a program with the line

```
|/home/myaccount/my_rails_app/production/script/runner 
    'EBlast.receive(STDIN.read)' -e production`
```

The problem is that the entire contents of `STDIN.read` is dumped in the log. I don't want any of that. It gets dumped before the `EBlast.receive` method is even called because I put a custom log entry on the first line of that method and the email contents are logged before that is.

How do I stop `STDIN.read` from being logged? It's blowing up my log file.

EDIT: Maybe it isn't something that the script/runner is doing, but rather what mail server is doing somehow? I noticed that in my logs whenever I actually send AND receive the emails through the rails app, the email contents are logged. When the email is sent,

> Sent mail to [email address]

appears before the email contents...when I receive an email through script/runner,

> Received mail:

appears before the email contents.

Comment: That seems very strange. What if you just run `script/runner "STDIN.read" -e production` and type in some garbage. Do you see that in the log file?

Comment: How do I actually -finish- typing into STDIN? I hit Enter, Shift+Enter, whatever...it won't exit the STDIN input until I hit Ctrl+c which it then gives me an 'interruption' error message. Nothing in log.

Comment: Use CNTRL + D to cancel STDIN from the command-line on Mac OS and *nix systems.

Comment: Nothing appears in the log when I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it has to do with the logger function of action_mailer! I put `ActionMailer::Base.logger = nil` in environment.rb

Problem solved.